# Sending and reading JSON in php

Tags: php, json

I'm working on sending an email from my site using a JSON. I'm doing it this way because simply sending it through the `<form>` control seems to bypass a little DIY "Are you human" validation I'm doing:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#contact-submit").click(function() {
        if ($("#contact-captcha").text != "green") {
            $("#contact-captcha").text = "Incorrect";
            $("#contact-captcha").css("border-color", "#7c0707");
        }
        else
        {
            sendMail();
        }
    });

    function sendMail() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'includes/contact.php',
            data: { to: 'me@this.com', from: $('#contact-email').text(), subject: $('#contact-subject').val(), message: $('#contact-message').val() }
        });
    }
</script>
```

The problem is now I can't figure out how to read the JSON data on `contact.php`.

I've seen tutorials that define the JSON in the php code and then use json_decode() to read it which is no good as I can't be defining the JSON there.

Can anyone provide any guidance as to how to read the JSON here? I thought of using a querystring but can't figure out how to do that here.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This will send normal parameters, not a JSON string.

Comment: is this where I need to json_encode() or something? Never done this before...

Comment: On contact.php, just check for $_POST['to'] for to value that you are passing using function and same for other variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using

```
data: { to: 'me@this.com', from: $('#contact-email').text(), subject: $('#contact-subject').val(), message: $('#contact-message').val() }
```

You'll get the data in `$_POST['to']`, `$_POST['from']`, etc.

A better way (still not a JSON method), would be to use something like this:

```
var serialized = $("form").serialize();
serialized.to = "you@example.com";
$.ajax { ... data: serialized ... }
```

and have `from`, `subject`, and `message` be the `name` attributes of the input fields.

```
From: <input type="text" name="from"/>
```

If you DO want to send JSON (I don't see any reason to do it), you can do this:

```
json = JSON.stringify({ to: 'me@this.com', from: $('#contact-email').text(), subject: $('#contact-subject').val(), message: $('#contact-message').val() });
```

and send it using `data: { json: json }`, and finally do

```
json_decode($_POST['json']);
```

to get the associative array back.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're talking about as far as the serialize goes... All I want to do here is to send the data after the validation on the .click event. Don't care how it gets sent.

Comment: @Ortund, well then just see the first two lines of my answer :)

Comment: @Ortund, `serialize` would be useful if you have several inputs, so you won't have to select each one and call `text()` or `val()` on them.

Comment: I'll mark as answer because I can see that using $_POST[<value>]` is working. Thanks, that's all I needed

Answer (score 0):

In contacts.php

```
print_r($_POST)
```

or use Firebug and check in console during submit, you can easily find whether you data is sent properly (or whether it is in JSON.. so on)

(I'm not sure how you are doing your "Human verification" check, but, checking the field  value **$("#contact-captcha").text != "green"** not a right way(Ease to tamper and bypass it since its in form itself).
You need to create a hash in server side using a 'random' text and session it (or send to form) and user has to enter the text and send that along as POST to server. And finally verify by hash the user enter text and compare with one you have created it.
Ignore this if you're doing it correctly. ^^")

Answer (score 0):

If using JSON is not a must then you can do it this way.
Use the jquery code that you have used for sending the data to contacts.php and following PHP code.

In Contact.php

```
if(isset($_POST['to']) && $_POST['to'] != ''){

    $filterTO = $_POST['to'];

    //filter value and get filtered value back in $filterTO here and use it further
}
```

You can also use other variables in same way.
**Note**: It is higly recommended to filter variables before use. I have shown only the part which was problem for you. This is not entire standard process.